# sql server sync and windows phone 7

Tags: sql-server, windows-phone-7, synchronization

Can i do sync with windows phone 7 and SQL Server? 
If so, does anyone have any examples?

That would really be cool...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

the new version of the [Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/default) (currently CTP) supports your scenario.
It supports caching local data and syncing it back to a sql server database.

See [Microsoft Sync Framework and Windows Phone 7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg507824.aspx) for more information.

Comment: do you think sync framework still works and its not dead,since its not updated

Comment: do you think sync framework still works and its not dead,since its not updated

Answer (score 0):

There is no SQL Server product on Windows Phone 7 for you to sync with. There are a number of good local/embedded database solutions for Windows Phone 7 (such as the open source [Sterling](http://sterling.codeplex.com) project), but you would need to implement your own implementation for syncing any data.

Comment: i think the data is stored on the phone in isolated storage..not in SQL Compact